# All possible sums of consecutive number that equal to N in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find all the possible sums from consecutive elements in an array that add upto a particular number.
Ex:-

```
a[] = {4,7,2,1,3,8,5}; and N = 13,
Output = {4,7,2},{7,2,1,3},{8,5}
```

Here is my code -

```
 int low = 0;
        int high = 0;
        int sum = a[0];
        while(high < a.length) {
            if(sum < 13) {
                high++;

                if(high < a.length) {
                    sum+= a[high];

                }
            } else if(sum > 13) {
                sum-=a[low];
                low++;

            }
            if(sum == 13) {
                for(int i=low;i<=high;i++) {
                    System.out.println(a[i]);
                }
                System.out.println("new ");
                low++;
                high++;
                sum = 0;
                //return;
            }
        }
```

But the output is returning only one set  `{4,7,2}` . I am unable to print the other sets. Can anyone please help me fix this

Comment: Does the array contain positive numbers only?

Comment: Yes, If i want to support -ve numbers how can I handle them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not resetting the variables correctly after you find the first sequence :

```
        if(sum == 13) {
            for(int i=low;i<=high;i++) {
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("new ");
            low++;
            high++; // change to high = low; // since you want your loop to test 
                    // sequences that start at the new (post incremented) low
            sum = 0; // change to sum = a[low]; // since the initial sum is the value of
                     // the first element in the new sequence
        }
```

Comment: Alternatively you could also keep the line `high++;` the way it is and change `sum = 0;` to `if(high < a.length) sum += a[high];` and btw. if you want to support zeros in your array you just have to remove the line `low++`;

Answer (score 0):

If the array may contain zero or negative numbers.

```
    int a[] = {4,7,2,1,3,8,5,-1,1};
    int length = a.length;
    for (int low = 0; low < length; ++low) {
        int sum = a[low];
        for (int high = low + 1; high < length; ++high) {
            sum += a[high];
            if (sum == 13) {
                for (int k = low; k <= high; ++k)
                    System.out.print(a[k] + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

result:

```
4 7 2 
7 2 1 3 
8 5 
8 5 -1 1
```